Не запускается Pixelorama на Ubuntu
после установки решил запустить, ничего не происходило, открыл через терминал, вижу это (libc6 установлен)
/snap/pixelorama/217/Pixelorama.x86_64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: 
version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /snap/pixelorama/217/Pixelorama.x86_64)

а это через судо
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
/snap/pixelorama/217/Pixelorama.x86_64: 
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' 
not found (required by /snap/pixelorama/217/Pixelorama.x86_64)


можно с исходника попробовать пересобрать https://github.com/Orama-Interactive/Pixelorama

спасибо, не надо, уже ищу альтернативы :)

Какая версия Ubuntu хоть?

Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
